# match item search like Google - PHP code

Tags: php, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

I wanna write a function like this
function (str, find){}
such that when I have a str like

> Hello every body, HeLlo and hElLo everyone blah

and term find like "hello", i get the result

```
<span class="match">Hello</span> every body, <span class="match">HeLlo</span> and <span class="match">hElLo</span> everyone blah
```

Comment: Duplicate. Search the answers, this type of question has been answered a lot in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('~Hello~i', '<span blabla>\0</span>', 'Hello every body, HeLlo and hElLo everyone blah');
```

gives

```
<span blabla>Hello</span> every body, <span blabla>HeLlo</span> and <span blabla>hElLo</span> everyone blah
```